# Error building Tensorflow pip-package in windows OS

Tags: tensorflow, pip, bazel

Im trying to build tensorflow pip package but i am getting an error which is hard to understand for me. Below is the message printed by mysys64. Does anybody have an idea what I need to do to fix this?

```
Master Tk@DESKTOP-BJH5T82 MSYS /C/tensorflow
$ bazel build -c opt $BUILD_OPTS tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
...................
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
    currently loading: tensorflow/tools/pip_package
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (1 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (2 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (4 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (4 packages loaded)

WARNING: C:/tools/msys64/tmp/_bazel_master tk/x1e5egqw/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in C:/tools/msys64/tmp/_bazel_master tk/x1e5egqw/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) 
does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a build error in future versions

Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (62 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (66 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (70 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (70 packages loaded)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (70 packages loaded)

ERROR: C:/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/BUILD:20:1: no such package '@eigen_archive//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 88
                _apply_patch(ctx, ctx.attr.patch_file)
        File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 59, in _apply_patch
                _execute_and_check_ret_code(ctx, cmd)
        File "C:/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 44, in _execute_and_check_ret_code
                fail("Non-zero return code({1}) when ...))
Non-zero return code(2) when executing 'c:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c patch -p1 -d C:/tools/msys64/tmp/_bazel_master tk/x1e5egqw/external/eigen_archive -i C:/tensorflow/third_party/eigen_fix_cuda_compilation.patch':
Stdout:
Stderr: patch: **** Can't change to directory C:/tools/msys64/tmp/_bazel_master : No such file or directory
 and referenced by '//third_party/eigen3:eigen3'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build abort ed: Loading failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 40.537s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (70 packages loaded)
```

Comment: Worth noting: ["We *do not support* building TensorFlow on Windows."](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)

Comment: @hoefling Yes, I read that line in the documents. However it is possible to build tensorflow from source using windows (see https://github.com/kalaspuffar/tensorflow-mnist-test/blob/master/README.md). The problem I think I am facing is with the warning I received.